# Splitting the dataframe column in key-value pair across multiple column in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have data in excel which I am trying to analyze in R. How do I split the column in my dataframe which contains information in key-value pair into multiple columns.

for example:

```
Id        col1
1         Name: Joe Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua UID: 23456 Location:NY CTN: ************************************
2         CustName: Kim Putok Ctn: ************************************ Location: CA
3         Customer Name: GLORIA ;      CTN: ************************************      Affected CTN: ************************************ Location: Egypt
4         Customer Name: ; ;Leahi ;  Reason for the Call: ; ; ; Location: CA discription: xyz
5         auto pop / suspended line -cx speaking spanish -transfered call
```

Please note here data in `col1` is not in specific format and it contains lot of delimiters, data in the next line in same cell, data not in key-value pair (such type of data needs to be removed).

How do I tackle or clean such kind of data? How do I split such data in key-value pair across multiple columns? Any suggestion will be great help.

--EDIT--
My original data

```
> dput(head(asummy, 10))
structure(list(`arrange_df[, 12]` = c("Customer Name: JOE\r\nReason for the Call: BP Set Up\r\nResolution: \r\nvisual audit on the account\r\nset expectations in BP\r\noffered call back\r\nCenter Location: Clark\r\nCTN (Number Calling About): ************************************\r\nAVAYA (Number Calling From): ************************************\r\nAgent UID: cm***************************u\r\n", 
"Name: Kim Putok\r\nCtn: ************************************\r\nReason for calling: lost phone/ ************************************/ follow up on insurance claim/ routed to asurion\r\nResolution:\r\nLocation: Clark\r\nattuid: gb***************************r\r\n", 
"Customer Name: Heather \r\nReason for the Call:    got suspended / card issue / supposedly paid / complains she just updated online her card then got susp\r\nResolution:  \r\nCenter Location: Clark\r\nCTN:  ************************************\r\nAlt No:  ************************************\r\nCredit Reason:  ********* courtesy \r\nAgent UID: rc***************************w/I-EQR******************G\r\n", 
"Customer Name: GLORIA ;      CTN: ************************************      Affected CTN: ************************************      Alternate Number: none      Reason for the Call: change rate plan      Resolution: set exp on changing rate plan      Agent UID: gt***************************g", 
"Customer Name: BRANDY \r\nReason for the Call: payment\r\nRecommendations/Troubleshooting Steps:\r\nResolution: explained card errors\r\nasked for alt # but no good\r\noffered to use different card or refill card\r\nsent qp link\r\nshe will go to bank to check as per cx\r\nCenter Location:\r\nCTN: ************************************\r\nCredit Reason (If credit was applied to account):\r\nAgent UID: jq***************************n\r\n", 
"Customer Name: ; ;Leahi ;  Reason for the Call: ; ; ;billing issue / ******************.****************** dollars only orig. bill / due date shld be *********th / why ****************** now? / ctn change questions ;  Resolution: ; ;explained bill / ctn change info provided ;  Center Location: ;Clark  CTN: ; ;************************************  Alt No:  Credit Reason:  Agent UID: rc***************************w/I-K*********GMDR", 
"Customer Name: MICHAEL\r\nReason for the Call: ACCOUNT BAL INQ\r\n\r\nRecommendations/Troubleshooting Steps:\r\n*Account verified and provided information\r\n\r\nResolution: \r\n*calling about the account status\r\n*suspended due to BBP\r\n*adv about BP policy\r\n*Provided payment options\r\n\r\nCenter Location:Clark\r\nCTN************************************:\r\nCredit Reason (If credit was applied to account):\r\nAgent UID:rc*********\r\n", 
"Customer Name: Kimberly\r\nCTN: ************************************\r\nAffected CTN:************************************\r\nAlternate Number: none\r\nReason for the Call: add mhs otc $******************\r\nResolution: added mhs otc  $******************\r\nAgent UID: gt***************************g\r\n", 
"auto pop / suspended line\r\n-cx speaking spanish\r\n-transfered call\r\n", 
"Customer Name: TERRELL ;  Reason for the Call: payment  Recommendations/Troubleshooting Steps:  Resolution: payment success  test and validated  CTN: ************************************  Credit Reason (If credit was applied to account):  Agent UID: jq***************************n"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please could you produce a minimal, [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (probably using `dput()`)? This will help others to solve your problem. Which data do you want to separate? Are the delimiters all the same, or do they differ?

Comment: With such messy data it‘s usually not possible to come up with a straightforward splitting scheme. You best bet is probably to split up the column by colon and semicolon or based on a regex pattern and then check if you still need to juggle around some values.

Comment: @CaptainHat - Delimiters are not same. I have edited the question and added `dput()`. I need all the data from the column which are in the key-value pair in such a way that each key-value pair is splitted across multiple column. If any of the element is not in key-value pair then that needs to be ignored or removed.

Comment: @deschen - Thanks for your input. I tried to split the column based on delimiter and regex but nothing works for me. I have edited the question. please check, any suggestion will be great help.

Comment: There are two separate issues here. First is getting your data into some sort of structure where a column contains a key-value pair and only that pair. Second is splitting those pairs into separate columns. You can do the latter easily using `tidyr::separate()`. The former is going to be a lot of manual idiosyncratic cleaning.

Comment: @socialscientist - My dataset is very large more than 4000 record, it is impossible to clean data manually.

Comment: Manual = writing ad-hoc code unlikely to apply to any other data set. Unless, of course, there is more structure to your data than you have communicated - in which case it should be straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to find a regex that matches the "separators" of your text. For example ': ' seems to be one of them. Here is a possible regex, but it does not work fully

```r
library(tidyverse)
df = tribble(~ Id, ~ col1,
        "1", "Name: Joe Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua UID: 23456 Location:NY CTN: ************************************",
        "2", "CustName: Kim Putok Ctn: ************************************ Location: CA",
        "3", "Customer Name: GLORIA ;      CTN: ************************************      Affected CTN: ************************************ Location: Egypt",
        "4", "Customer Name: ; ;Leahi ;  Reason for the Call: ; ; ; Location: CA discription: xyz",
        "5", "auto pop / suspended line -cx speaking spanish -transfered call")

regex <- ': |;' # TO BE MODIFIED TO SATISFY THE PROBLEM
lapply(1:nrow(df), \(i) strsplit(df$col1[i], regex))
```

To find the right regex, use this tool : https://www.autoregex.xyz/

Once the good regex has been found, one of these functions may be useful : `strsplit`, `extract`, `separate` (`tidyr` package)

It's not over yet, but it's the beginning of a solution

Answer (score 1):

My advice: rather than treat this dataset as a given, find out more about how it was generated. For instance, the sample you provided seems to have two types of row, one where the name:value pairs are separated by \r\n (these are easy to parse), and one where they are not (these are a lot harder to parse). I suspect there is another column in your dataset that distinguishes these, but you did not provide that. For instance, I notice you provided column 12 of `arrange_df`. What's in the other columns?

For the first type, in rows 1,2,3,5,7, and 8,

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
#
df <- structure(list(`x` = c("Customer Name: JOE\r\nReason for the Call: BP Set Up\r\nResolution: \r\nvisual audit on the account\r\nset expectations in BP\r\noffered call back\r\nCenter Location: Clark\r\nCTN (Number Calling About): ************************************\r\nAVAYA (Number Calling From): ************************************\r\nAgent UID: cm***************************u\r\n", 
                                            "Name: Kim Putok\r\nCtn: ************************************\r\nReason for calling: lost phone/ ************************************/ follow up on insurance claim/ routed to asurion\r\nResolution:\r\nLocation: Clark\r\nattuid: gb***************************r\r\n", 
                                            "Customer Name: Heather \r\nReason for the Call:    got suspended / card issue / supposedly paid / complains she just updated online her card then got susp\r\nResolution:  \r\nCenter Location: Clark\r\nCTN:  ************************************\r\nAlt No:  ************************************\r\nCredit Reason:  ********* courtesy \r\nAgent UID: rc***************************w/I-EQR******************G\r\n", 
                                            "Customer Name: GLORIA ;      CTN: ************************************      Affected CTN: ************************************      Alternate Number: none      Reason for the Call: change rate plan      Resolution: set exp on changing rate plan      Agent UID: gt***************************g", 
                                            "Customer Name: BRANDY \r\nReason for the Call: payment\r\nRecommendations/Troubleshooting Steps:\r\nResolution: explained card errors\r\nasked for alt # but no good\r\noffered to use different card or refill card\r\nsent qp link\r\nshe will go to bank to check as per cx\r\nCenter Location:\r\nCTN: ************************************\r\nCredit Reason (If credit was applied to account):\r\nAgent UID: jq***************************n\r\n", 
                                            "Customer Name: ; ;Leahi ;  Reason for the Call: ; ; ;billing issue / ******************.****************** dollars only orig. bill / due date shld be *********th / why ****************** now? / ctn change questions ;  Resolution: ; ;explained bill / ctn change info provided ;  Center Location: ;Clark  CTN: ; ;************************************  Alt No:  Credit Reason:  Agent UID: rc***************************w/I-K*********GMDR", 
                                            "Customer Name: MICHAEL\r\nReason for the Call: ACCOUNT BAL INQ\r\n\r\nRecommendations/Troubleshooting Steps:\r\n*Account verified and provided information\r\n\r\nResolution: \r\n*calling about the account status\r\n*suspended due to BBP\r\n*adv about BP policy\r\n*Provided payment options\r\n\r\nCenter Location:Clark\r\nCTN************************************:\r\nCredit Reason (If credit was applied to account):\r\nAgent UID:rc*********\r\n", 
                                            "Customer Name: Kimberly\r\nCTN: ************************************\r\nAffected CTN:************************************\r\nAlternate Number: none\r\nReason for the Call: add mhs otc $******************\r\nResolution: added mhs otc  $******************\r\nAgent UID: gt***************************g\r\n", 
                                            "auto pop / suspended line\r\n-cx speaking spanish\r\n-transfered call\r\n", 
                                            "Customer Name: TERRELL ;  Reason for the Call: payment  Recommendations/Troubleshooting Steps:  Resolution: payment success  test and validated  CTN: ************************************  Credit Reason (If credit was applied to account):  Agent UID: jq***************************n"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

setDT(df)[, ID:=seq(.N)]
f <- \(str) {stri_match_all_regex(str, '(.+)\\:(.+)')[[1]]}

parsed <- df[c(1,3,5,7,8), as.data.table(f(x)[, 2:3]), by=.(ID)]
```